# Почему на wordpess конфликтуют jquery и jquery-ui и я получаю ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Почему на wordpress при попытке подключить jquery и jquery-ui
в коде я получаю такую ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined
at b.(/wor/ru/2019/02/20/%d0%b4%d0%be/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDown (localhost/wor/wp-content/themes/me_theme_test/code...
at HTMLDivElement. (jquery-ui.min.js:22)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5)
at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:5)
_mouseDown @ jquery-ui.min.js:24
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:22
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
2jquery-ui.min.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
at b.(/wor/ru/2019/02/20/%d0%b4%d0%be/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (localhost/wor/wp-content/themes/me_theme_test/code...
at HTMLDocument._mouseMoveDelegate (jquery-ui.min.js:24)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5)
at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery.min.js:5)
```

Вот пример кода который работает [code](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/gZdvJN)

Я уже пытался и удалять оригинальный jquery и переустанавливать его

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_script_method' );
function jquery_script_method() {
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/code/js/jquery.min.js', false, null, false );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );    
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/code/js/jquery-ui.min.js',array( 'jquery' ), null, false); 
}
```

и встраивать через wp_head

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_wp_custom_code', 9999 );
function my_wp_custom_code() {
echo '<script src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/code/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
echo '<script src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/code/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
}
```

и просто через тег script в файле content.php

и совмещал jquery и jquery-ui в один js файл

я пытался обновить 
jquery с v1.10.2 до v3.3.1
jquery-ui с 1.8.2 до v1.12.1
появилась ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
at functions.js?ver=20150315:149
at functions.js?ver=20150315:210
```

jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js исправил ошибку Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
но ошибка в jquery-ui осталась
Что делать я не знаю идеи закончились.

Comment: Касательно первого варианта, попробуйте подключить [jquery migrate](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/)

Comment: @Nilsan я же уже написал что jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js не помог

Comment: _обновить jquery с v1.10.2 до v3.3.1 jquery-ui с 1.8.2 до v1.12.1_ попробуйте jquery-ui оставить в актуальноу версии + jquery актуальную + jquery migrate актуальную